# Ubuntu 13.10 internet problems - Also with 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 13.10, ethernet

Just installed 13.10 on a new build, and I'm having a few issues. The main one being with internet. My motherboard has a realtek ethernet adapter built in, and while it does connect, it does not get an IP address, nor can it ping the router.

Secondly, my wifi adapter (TP-link WDN4800) can see the wireless networks, and on connection prompts for a password, it never actually connects.

I can connect to the router both with wired and wireless from other machines in my house, and I have tried manually assigning IP addresses in case that was the issue. I have also tried the fix suggested here: http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/ca/2012-11-01-tp-link-tl-wdn4800-wireless-n-dual-band-pcie-450mbps with no luck.

At present I am connected to the WIFI via my iPhone (USB).

Would appreciate any help. I enjoy Ubuntu once it's working, but setting it up is proving to be a real pain.

EDIT:
Also tried 12.04 LTS - both issues are present here too.

EDIT 2 - running `dmesg | grep -E 'cfg|ath|wlan'` gives:

```
[  835.322749] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  836.295689] wlan0: authenticate with 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0
[  836.303592] wlan0: direct probe to 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0 (try 1/3)
[  836.507237] wlan0: direct probe to 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0 (try 2/3)
[  836.711325] wlan0: direct probe to 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0 (try 3/3)
[  836.915507] wlan0: authentication with 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0 timed out
[  837.344859] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026800
[  837.516237] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.580301] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.592172] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026800
[  837.592205] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  837.656339] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.668245] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026800
[  837.668280] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  837.732029] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.743565] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  837.743587] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  837.808400] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.820465] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00024e00
[  837.820501] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  837.884470] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.896318] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  837.896354] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  837.960517] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  837.972402] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  837.972436] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  838.036558] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  838.100608] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  838.112503] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026e00
[  838.112533] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  838.176699] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  838.188617] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  838.188646] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  838.252692] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  838.264553] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  838.264585] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.309136] wlan0: deauthenticating from 08:76:ff:c8:67:d0 by local choice (reason=3)
[  841.478857] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.490702] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  841.490737] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.558863] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.570786] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026800
[  841.570823] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.634987] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.646875] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  841.646910] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.710992] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.774983] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.786866] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  841.786896] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.851053] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.862974] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  841.863006] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  841.927042] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  841.938943] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026e00
[  841.938974] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  842.003202] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  842.067251] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  842.079114] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  842.079147] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  842.143292] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  842.155151] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00026800
[  842.155182] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
[  842.219331] ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
[  842.231204] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  842.231232] ath: phy0: Could not stop RX, we could be confusing the DMA engine when we start RX up
```

any thoughts? It's looking like hardware issues.